# What is the correct way to access data fetched from a redux thunk function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am currently using this pattern, but it feels a bit wrong. I don't think a redux thunk should return a string, and the component should only access the data fetched through the connected props. I may be wrong, but is there a better, more idiomatic way of doing this?

I want to keep the two thunks separate so that I can call each one individually.

```
// actions
const putCustomer = ...;
const putBooking = ...;

// thunks
export async function fetchCustomer(customerId) {
  return dispatch => {
    const customer = await customerApi.fetch(customerId);
    dispatch(actions.putCustomer( {customer} ));
  };
}

export async function fetchBooking(bookingId) {
  return dispatch => {
    const booking = await bookingApi.fetch(bookingId);
    dispatch(actions.putBooking( {booking} ));

    // I AM RETURNING THE BOOKING DATA HERE
    return booking;
  };
}

// component
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  async componentWillMount() {
    const booking = await this.props.dispatch(fetchBooking(this.props.bookingId));

    // I WANT TO ACCESS THE BOOKING DATA HERE
    this.props.dispatch(fetchCustomer(booking.customerId));
  }
}
```

**QUESTION UPDATED**

- Added some comments where I want to access the data

Comment: so can you elaborate more on this , if i m understanding right then you mean if you dispatch the action then what is right way to fetch the data after that?

Comment: I mean should I be returning data from the thunk (the line I marked 'I return the booking here'), so yes I think you understand correctly. I know I can connect the component and get the data via connected props, but I want to get hold of the booking data straight away in the next line in the componentWIllMount function I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Ideal case below is the how the flow goes incase you dispatch some action :

[image]

> It is suggested that UI can be bind to state and state is been modified by reducer , its a single direction flow. The data you are trying to return can be managed via state and the dispatcher can modify that state

Comment: So I guess the line below my comment '// I WANT TO ACCESS THE BOOKING DATA HERE' should go in componentWIllReceiveProps, when the props have updated? It seems a bit messy

Comment: no , when dispatch is called it will change the state of app and from mapStateToProps you can get the changed state

Comment: But in my example above, I only want to call `fetchCustomer(booking.customerId)` once. Where should this go?

Comment: in action , which will perform you fetch customer task and save the result in state , so incase you would require that result , you can take from state